# Python convert string to list

Tags: python

How can we convert

```
['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]']
```

to

```
[[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]]
```

without quotes. I tried using eval, list, tuple, replace and s.strip() but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help on this

Comment: Is the input a string or a list containing a string? Do you mean the result is a string with no single quotes in it, or the result is a list containing a list containing float values, or other? If the first, just remove all quotes with the `replace()` method. If the second, realize that the usual printing of a list includes commas between the values.

Comment: What is the source of the data? How about you fix it there rather than later?

Comment: Is it a string or a list?

Comment: Do you mean converting it from a list containing a string to a list containing a list or a string to a string? By the power of the close vote, I declare this question unclear. Learn [ask].

Comment: I tried replace as testX2=[testX1.replace(" ' ","")] but again the answer is ['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]'] . I have to pass it to numpy so I need something like [[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]]

Comment: @shaifaliGupta ` [[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]]` isn't a list,  do you mean with the apostrophes?

Comment: @shaifaliGupta Is the original data structure a list or a string?

Comment: @shaifaliGupta if your not going to clarify, then we can't help. And I and other users have the privilege of closing or deleting your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
lst = ['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]']
item = ''.join(lst)
final_str = "[" + item + "]"
print (final_str)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` and `eval`:

```
>>> x = ['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]']
>>> x = [eval(x[0].replace(' ',','))]
>>> x
[[0.0034596999, 0.0034775001, 0.0010091923]]
```

Of course you can simply convert it to `numpy` array.

Answer (score 0):

Use .split() and .replace():

```
b = ['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]']
b = b[0].split(' ')
a = array([[float(x.replace('[','').replace(']','')) for x in b]])
print a
[[ 0.0034597   0.0034775   0.00100919]]
```

Don't use array() if you want a list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `eval` failed is because the string you consider as a string, is not a valid list representation - it doesn't contains commas.

You can convert it to a real list by taking of the square brackets, splitting the remaining string to separate string representing numbers, and eventually convert each such a string to a number. Here is the code:

```
data = ['[0.0034596999 0.0034775001 0.0010091923]']

s = data[0]
for ch in "[]":  # remove barckets
    s = s.replace(ch, '')

# splitting and converting to a list of floats
lst = [float(x) for x in s.split()]
```